# using google search api successfully

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

What am I missing here except proper `Google` public key?
I am getting the error (see below code)
while registering to get

```
    __author__ = ''

    import pprint

    from apiclient.discovery import build

    def main():
        ""241d57c296bd9ca73c09a51b422484e879be76cd""
        service = build("customsearch", "v1",
                        developerKey=google_api_public_key)

        res = service.cse().list(
            q='lectures').execute()
        pprint.pprint(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

   service = build("customsearch", "v1",
                    developerKey="public_key")  
    res = service.cse().list(
        q='lectures').execute()  
        #, cx='017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve').execute()  
    pprint.pprint(res)
```

Error:

```
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=lectures&alt=json&key=241d57c296bd9ca73c09a51b422484e879be76cd returned "Bad Request">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong API key.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```